# Trying to blur the background of the image and bring a rectangular box on the face using python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to bring a rectangular box on the face of the image first then I am trying to blur the background of the image in (frame variable) and extract face in (face variable)
On executing the code I get Error: frame not defined.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/HP/l.jpg')
#image=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Load the cascade
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

plt.imshow(image1)
faces = detector.detectMultiScale(
    image,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=10,
    minSize=(10, 50),
    
)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (1, 255, 4), 10)
    face=image1[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    frame=cv2.blur(image1,ksize = (10,10))
    frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]=face
plt.imshow(frame)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(face)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working fine only check is image is actually at the provided path because it may be image error try this create a folder in the file where you are running the image as images then replace **cv2.imread('\images\imagename.jpg')** instead of this **cv2.imread('C:/Users/HP/l.jpg')** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK1wH.png)

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/HP/l.jpg')
image = cv2.imread('images/1,jpg')
#image=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```